# Android App works on emulator, but not in real device

Tags: android

Well, I have a problem. Just ended writting app and start it on my Android emulator and everything works fine without any errors or something like that. But when I tried this exactly app on my real device(Android 2.3.5 GingerBread) my app doesn't even start and I get force close with a bunch of errors in my Logcat. Here I will provide my code.

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CrazyTipCalc" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/bill_text_view" />

    <!-- android:ems defines the width of the EditText box -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billEditText"
        android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/final_bill_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/final_bill_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billTextView"
        android:text="@string/change_tip_text_view" />

    <!-- android:progress="15" defines the default for the SeekBar -->

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:progress="15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_friendly_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/specCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/intro_spec_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/opinionCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/specCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/specCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/intro_opinion_text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availableTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/available_text_view" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availableTextView"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/availableBadRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/available_bad_radio_button" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/availableOkRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/available_ok_radio_button" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/availableGoodRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/available_good_radio_button" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/problemSpinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/problemSpinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="@string/time_waiting_text_view" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timeWaitingChronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
        android:text="Chronometer" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/problemSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:entries="@array/problem_solving" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startChronometerButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/start_chronometer_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startChronometerButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startChronometerButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:text="@string/pause_chronometer_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetChronometerButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
        android:text="@string/reset_chronometer_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.crazytipcalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Constants used when saving and restoring

    private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
    private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
    private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

    // Set default values for EditText's

    private double billBeforeTip;
    private double tipAmount;
    private double finalBill;

    // Declare EditTexts

    EditText billBeforeTipET;
    EditText tipAmountET;
    EditText finalBillET;

    // Sum of all radio buttons and check boxes

    private int[] checkListValues = new int[12];

    // Declare CheckBoxes

    CheckBox friendlyCheckBox;
    CheckBox specCheckBox;
    CheckBox opinionCheckBox;

    // Declare RadioButtons

    RadioGroup availableRadioGroup;
    RadioButton availableBadRadio;
    RadioButton availableOkRadio;
    RadioButton availableGoodRadio;

    // Declare Spinner

    Spinner problemSpinner;

    // Declare Buttons

    Button startChronometerButton;
    Button pauseChronometerButton;
    Button resetChronometerButton;

    // Declare chronometer

    Chronometer timeWaitingChronometer;

    // The number of seconds you spent
    // wating for the waitress

    long secondsYouWaited = 0;

    // TextView for the chronometer

    TextView timeWaitingTextView;

    // Declare Seekbar

    SeekBar tipSeekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check if app just started, or if it is being restored

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // Just started

            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            tipAmount = .15;
            finalBill = 0.0;
        } else {

            // App is being restored

            billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
            tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
            finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);

        }

        /* INITIALIZING ALL THE VARIABLES AND ID'S */

        // Initialize EditTexts

        billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
        tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
        finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);

        // Initialize Seekbar and add ChangeListener

        tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);

        tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);

        // Add change listener for when the bill before tip is changed

        billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

        // Initialize CheckBoxes

        friendlyCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendlyCheckBox);
        specCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.specCheckBox);
        opinionCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opinionCheckBox);

        setUpIntroCheckBoxes();

        // Initialize RadioButtons

        availableRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.availableRadioGroup);
        availableBadRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableBadRadio);
        availableOkRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableOkRadio);
        availableGoodRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableGoodRadio);

        addChangeListenerToRadios();

        // Initialize Spinner

        problemSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problemSpinner);

        addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner();

        // Initialize buttons

        startChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startChronometerButton);
        pauseChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseChronometerButton);
        resetChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetChronometerButton);

        setButtonsOnClickListener();

        // Initialize chronometer

        timeWaitingChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingChronometer);

        // Initialize TextView

        timeWaitingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingTextView);

    }

    // Called when the bill before tip amount is changed

    private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            try {

                // Change the billBeforeTip to the new input

                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                // Else make it default

                billBeforeTip = 0.0;

            }

            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    // Update the tip amount and add tip to bill to
    // find the final bill amount

    private void updateTipAndFinalBill() {

        // Get tip amount

        double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());

        // The bill before tip amount was set in billBeforeTipListener
        // Get the bill plus the tip

        double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);

        // Set the total bill amount including the tip

        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
    }

    // Called when a device changes in some way. For example,
    // when a keyboard is popped out, or when the device is
    // rotated. Used to save state information that you'd like
    // to be made available.

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            // Get the value set on the SeekBar

            tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;

            // Set tipAmountET with the value from the SeekBar

            tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));

            // Update all the other EditTexts

            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private void setUpIntroCheckBoxes() {

        // Add ChangeListener to the friendlyCheckBox

        friendlyCheckBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                            boolean arg1) {

                        // Use java ternary operator to set the right values for
                        // each item on the waitress check box checklist

                        checkListValues[0] = (friendlyCheckBox.isChecked()) ? 4
                                : 0;

                        // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                        // Update all the other EditTexts

                        updateTipAndFinalBill();

                    }

                });

        // Add ChangeListener to the specialsCheckBox

        specCheckBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                            boolean arg1) {

                        // Use java ternary operator to set the right values for
                        // each item on the waitress check box checklist

                        checkListValues[1] = (specCheckBox.isChecked()) ? 1 : 0;

                        // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                        // Update all the other EditTexts

                        updateTipAndFinalBill();

                    }

                });

        // Add ChangeListener to the opinionCheckBox

        opinionCheckBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                            boolean arg1) {

                        // Use java ternary operator to set the right values for
                        // each item on the waitress check box checklist

                        checkListValues[2] = (opinionCheckBox.isChecked()) ? 2
                                : 0;

                        // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                        // Update all the other EditTexts

                        updateTipAndFinalBill();

                    }

                });

    }

    // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

    private void setTipFromWaitressChecklist() {

        int checkListTotal = 0;

        // Circle through all the checklist values to calculate
        // a total amount based on waitress performance

        for (int item : checkListValues) {

            checkListTotal += item;

        }

        // Set tipAmountET

        tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", checkListTotal * .01));

    }

    private void addChangeListenerToRadios() {

        availableRadioGroup
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                        checkListValues[3] = (availableBadRadio.isChecked()) ? -1
                                : 0;
                        checkListValues[4] = (availableOkRadio.isChecked()) ? 2
                                : 0;
                        checkListValues[5] = (availableGoodRadio.isChecked()) ? 4
                                : 0;

                        // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                        // Update all the other EditTexts

                        updateTipAndFinalBill();

                    }
                });

    }

    private void addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner() {

        problemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                checkListValues[6] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("Bad") ? -1 : 0;
                checkListValues[7] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("OK") ? 3 : 0;
                checkListValues[8] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem())
                        .equals("Good") ? 6 : 0;

                // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                // Update all the other EditTexts

                updateTipAndFinalBill();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    // Adds ClickListeners for buttons so they can control the chronometer

    private void setButtonsOnClickListener() {

        startChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Holds the number of milliseconds paused

                int stoppedMiliseconds = 0;

                // Get time from the chronometer

                String chronoText = timeWaitingChronometer.getText().toString();
                String array[] = chronoText.split(":");

                if (array.length == 2) {

                    // Find the seconds

                    stoppedMiliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                            + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;

                } else if (array.length == 3) {

                    // Find the minutes

                    stoppedMiliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60
                            * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                            + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
                }

                // Amount of time elapsed since the start button was
                // pressed, minus the time paused

                timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        - stoppedMiliseconds);

                // Set the number of seconds you have waited
                // This would be set for minutes in the real world
                // obviously. That can be found in array[2]

                secondsYouWaited = Long.parseLong(array[1]);

                updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(secondsYouWaited);

                // Start the chronometer

                timeWaitingChronometer.start();

            }

        });

        pauseChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timeWaitingChronometer.stop();

            }
        });

        resetChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                secondsYouWaited = 0;

            }
        });

    }

    private void updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(long secondsYouWaited) {

        checkListValues[9] = (secondsYouWaited > 10) ? -2 : 2;

        // Calculate tip using the waitress checklist options

        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

        // Update all the other EditTexts

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crazytipcalc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.crazytipcalc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat :

```
07-14 21:50:27.710: I/ApplicationPackageManager(3211): cscCountry is not German : SEB
07-14 21:50:27.921: D/AndroidRuntime(3211): Shutting down VM
07-14 21:50:27.921: W/dalvikvm(3211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211): java.lang.NumberFormatException
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at com.example.crazytipcalc.MainActivity.updateTipAndFinalBill(MainActivity.java:217)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at com.example.crazytipcalc.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:213)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at com.example.crazytipcalc.MainActivity$7.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:429)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-14 21:50:27.929: E/AndroidRuntime(3211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Appreciate any help from you guys :)

Comment: What is the value of @strings/tip_edit_text?  It looks like you're getting a numberFormatException there because of how things are getting initialized.

Comment: tip_edit_text value is ".15"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to parse a text field as numeric while it has non-numeric data in it.  You need to catch that exception and use a reasonable default.

It may just be blank, that would probably cause the same exception.

```
    double tipAmount = 0;
    try{
        tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
```

That code will catch the exception, ignore it, and use 0 as a default tip if it can't parse the value.

Comment: What exactly I should do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Is this value equal to `null` ?

```
double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the log it is obvious, that the error occurs on line 217 of the `MainActivity.java`. Maybe the content of the `tipAmountET` `textField` can not be converted to double?

Answer (score 0):

`CharSequence s` is a null. Always check for the null

```
if(s.length() > 0 && s!=null) {
    billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
} else {
    billBeforeTip = 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this some time ago (in Android 1.5 age - it used to happen on HTC Hero but not on equivalent simulator :). It appeared that the culprit was fractional part separator - I was receiving `,` while some calls (namely `Double.valueOf()`) were expecting `.`. Also I spotted (but I do not remember anything more now) that sometimes I also had  (space) that caused similar confusion. My approach to `fix` that problem was to always replace `,` with `.` and to get rid of any space (so basically replace  with `` and crashes were gone.